# Sending mail in localhost:25 with Ssmtp

Tags: smtp, ssmtp

I already have Ssmtp installed and working in a Centos 5.7 machine with Gmail configured.

I can send mails in th shell without problems.

Now i want to use the ssmtp to allow a web app (installed in the same machine) to send mails but for do this i have to find a way to ssmtp "hears" in the port 25 (or any other).

There is a way to do this? There is another simple alternative to ssmtp who allows to send mail using localhost:25?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a web app to send mail, I'd recommend just using the "mail" command line.  pipe/redirect/print the mail to the input of mail, command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a webapp for sending mails the best way is to specify the conectivity for the app, you must specify the  protocol ,smtp_host, port, user and password if what you want its to send mails through an account. If you want to use smpt of gmail use `ssl://smtp.googlemail.com`

If u dont know the port of where smpt you should scan your ports (like with an nmap)